# How to include header/footer/etc.php with content in between for each page?

Tags: php, templates, frameworks, include, backend

I'm looking for an object-oriented solution or possibly a framework that already exists to do what I'm hoping to do for a somewhat small back-end/admin project.

For instance, the system is to manage Projects.  So there will be a header/footer/menu on every page.  Two pages, for instance, will be projects.php and notes.php.

To include the header and footer on these pages I would normally do:

```
//header.php
<!-- Header Content Here -->
include menu.php

//projects.php
include header.php
<!-- My Projects Content Here -->
include footer.php

//notes.php
include header.php
<!-- My Projects Content Here -->
include footer.php
```

and have my links to each page just be '/projects/' or '/notes/'

I've also tried:

```
//index.php
include header.php
include projects.php
include notes.php
include footer.php

//projects.php
if(isset($_GET['projects']) {
<!-- My Projects Content Here -->

//notes.php
if(isset($_GET['notes']) {
<!-- My Notes Content Here -->
```

and have the links in my menu be '/index.php?projects' and '/index.php?notes'.

Both are frustrating and don't seem very fluid to me.  I would like to upgrade my tactics here but am unsure the best way to go about it.

What's the best way?  Is there a Framework that is lightweight and can manage these for me?  I would like to keep the links at '/projects/' and '/notes/' but just be able to create an object that calls the content from projects.php and places it in automatically on that link click.

TLDR; - I don't want to have to place header/footer/etc.php as an 'include X' into every PHP page template file manually.  I would like for it to know that every page needs it unless otherwise assigned.

Comment: Why not use `$_GET['page']` which is equal to projects or notes. Based on the get your can load (include) the right php file

Comment: That's just the inverse of my second solution, right?  Seems like the same annoyance there would exist it would just be written differently.

Comment: No beceause you don't have to write an if statement for evey file. Assuming that every header, footer, menu file consist of the same content

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If not or if you still have problems update the question and let us know

Comment: Yea, definitely helped.  I guess what I was looking for isn't feasible or I wasn't explaining it properly.  I was hoping there was a better way.  i.e., something like just having $projects = new PageTemplate(); and then have a list of the page objects that would be called and loaded when the subdirector was called.. like have the url /projects/.  I didn't want to have any ?= variables in the url unless they were actually editing.. so like projects/?edit=1?project_id=12 instead of page.php?page=projects&edit=1&project_id=12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file called something like page.php:

```
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
  // Could add check to see if file exists
  $page = $_GET['page']; // Being "notes" or "projects" 

  include 'header.php'; // Assuming this includes <head>, header, menu, functions etc. 
  include $page.'.php'; // Makes notes.php or projects.php
  include 'footer.php';

} else {
 echo 'Someting went wrong';
}
```

For links in menu it should be `page.php?page=notes` or `page.php?page=projects`

Answer (score 0):

Every file?  Are you really sure you want to do that?  It might cause data crash.

But if you insist, look for your php.ini file and find `auto_prepend_file`
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

```
auto_prepend_file header.php // For Example
```

Now that you did that if you don't remove header.php from every program (or make sure include_once is used) then you might have php errors flying around.

Comment: Well, not physically every file; as I also have files like "functions.php" that contain real functions that don't display anything.

But, I would like to add header.php to the top of every "page of type X", for instance.

Comment: This only applies to the file being called, not every file that exists  so if you include `functions.php` you don't get a 2nd copy of `header.php`